# Read out USB-Device with evtest

Tags: usb, scanner

we have an ubuntu server running in our network.
At this server we have connected an usb barcodescanner, which is read out via `evtest` and `cut`.
So now we have the problem, that the scanner data is only read out at the 2nd scan attempt.
We get the full barcode we have scanned and the half of the same barcode again as a result.

Is there any option to read the keys out at the first time and not after scanning each code two times?

Best regards

EDIT:
Posted the Solution to a seperate answer and marked it as the solution.

Comment: You found an answer, and wrote it down here, which is very good! But there is a small technical problem: After editing the question to add the answer as part of the question text, and adding "SOLVED" to the title, the technical state is still an unanswered question - people will spend time on reading it again trying to answer. You can just answer your own question - moving the "update" part there; And then, accept it as the right answer, using the chekmark.

Comment: Dear Volker,
thanks for the hint. I'll change that. :)

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE(02-12-2014) We already solved the problem. Instead of evtest we created a script which reads out a user input and use that to get the barcodes from the scangun.